# Angular startup issue

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular as i'm trying to build one basic example but when i tried i get the issue below. Can any one help me with this i already ran an npm install and node js is already installed.

when i ran the below command in Visual Studio terminal i am getting below issue.

> PS `<HelloApp>` ng serve
>   ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> ```
> At line:1 char:1
> + ng serve
> + ~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng serve command not working angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811124/ng-serve-command-not-working-angular-5)

Comment: angularJS or angular5 ?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps given on angular.io to get started with angular ? If not, then please go ahead and try that first.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ng.ps1 from the directory

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

then try clearing the npm cache at

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install angular using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```